# Is there free Wi-Fi at Quimper Cornouaille Airport?

Tags: wifi, brittany, uip

The [airport website](http://www.quimper.aeroport.fr/index.php?lang=en) for Quimper Cornouaille Airport doesn't seem to mention anything either way about Wi-Fi.

Is there free Wi-Fi available here, and if so, can you just access it or do you need to do something to get a login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is!

If you rummage through all the PDFs in the French bit of the airport website, you'll fine the details [hidden in this brouchure](http://www.quimper.aeroport.fr/images/file/GH%20OK.pdf). Alternately, just ask at the cafe/bar in the airport, they're very friendly and helpful there :)

You need to go to the information (l’accueil) desk, which doubles up as the Air France ticket desk (and is much better signed for the latter than the former!). If you ask there for a password, they'll take your name, wander back into the office and generate you a personal password for the day. You can then connect to the `aeroport` Wi-Fi, trigger the captive portal, enter your password and get online.

However... It's a very small airport, and people there have multiple roles. So, if you want to get the password just as a flight is about to leave, you'll have to wait! (The staff who give out the password also help with flight dispatch) The good news is they're very friendly, and they'll come and find you with your password once the flight has gone!

Answer (score 1):

Another cunning way to find out is to look on Foursquare.

Their page for [Quimper Airport](https://foursquare.com/v/a%C3%A9roport-de-quimper/4c05351e0d0e0f47b7f9049a) has the following tips:

- Il y a le wifi gratuit ici. Demandez un mot a clet a l'information / billets de Air France (basically There is free wifi here. Request password from Air France)
- They have free wifi, ask at the information desk (shared with the Air France ticket desk) and they'll sort you out with a password

So yes, they do have free Wi-Fi, ask at the Information desk for a password :)

Comment: You might want to check the date and author of those FourSquare entries... I added them just after the nice lady from the information desk came over with my password :)

Comment: Haha, that's awesome.  On the upside, my technique still worked for me :D

Comment: @Gagravarr In case you can edit your entry: I'm guessing that by “mot à clé” you meant either password = *mot de passe* or key = *clé*. More idiomatic French: *Demandez un mot de passe au bureau d'informations et billets Air France*.

Comment: Thanks Giles, Foursquare tip edited and corrected! At some point I'll work out how to make auto-correct not mess everything up every time I try to write in French or Spanish...

Comment: His name is Gilles!